# Matching nullability of argument and return type's generic type parameters

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

```cs
public readonly struct Foo<T>
{
    // ...
    public T Value { get; }
}

public static Foo<string?> Bar(Foo<string?> foo)
{
    if (foo.Value is null) { /* Something */ }
    else { /* Some other thing */ }
    return foo;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var foo1 = new Foo<string>("s");
    var ret1 = Bar(foo1); // Warns because foo1's type parameter is not nullable

    var foo2 = new Foo<string?>("s");
    var ret2 = Bar(foo2); // Ok because foo2's type parameter is nullable
}
```

- Can I write Bar to accept both `Foo<string?>` and `Foo<string>`?
- Can I annotate Bar to specify "what goes in goes out", so the nullability of `T` of the returning `Foo<T>` will be the same as the nullability of `T` of the parameter `Foo<T>`?

Comment: There are a bunch of attributes that lets you annotate *some* dependencies, but not all of them. Basically, it isn't intended to solve **all** problems with nullability, just most of them.

Comment: You can, for instance, set up a dependency that says "the result of this method call will not be null if it was called with a non-null reference", but you cannot nest that inside the types, only the values. I suggest creating two overloads and renaming one of them, perhaps with the TryXYZ method name prefix.

Comment: How about just making `Bar` generic too, like `public static Foo<T> Bar<T>(Foo<T> foo)`? https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwGIA7AV11wENhcYACGY62gWACh2ABAZjtkoAmEYrgCedAM4YopMBjoAxCBAA8AFQB87AN7s6+uj0XKAFGroA3SrgCUeg7rYHndAGrXS9ALyXrAbnt9AF9Aw15zd1xPOm06AHMYDD86ELZU5y4AJkMARgB2HVCjThykY1VNOgAhSih1DRMlCo06ADNlOycHUOdsVroTdogAOkjo7Ak6MgobGLoAegAqOgBlCABbRIALbGI4ukX5lJ6DGFwJelil1Y36CAwtmCg6B939w+Oul0M8tuUAr6fIqZTKhRzffRWZ5DHJ0HzEGAAd3KKhKAAYGgAiCSYmwAiG+Z6wDCwnw1KCDZQ5PHsE6Q2p/CDZeFIlHogD8WJxNMBzihfESzOqtUpTJ5ziCBlpaXYQA==

Comment: If the method is only supposed to be taking `Foo<string>` (nullable or non-nullable), then this creates its own problems, you now have a method that takes `Foo<anything>` and have to deal with that.

Comment: @Lasse - Yeah, I couldn't find one that allowed me to annotate this, I fear that there is no way. Your suggestion of having two different methods would surely work but it would be really ugly. And yes, having a null is valid for this method and I deal with that.

Comment: @thehennyy - It works if you don't need a string :D But in my case I need the specific type.

Comment: The actual use case is the type-specific validations in [Guard](https://github.com/safakgur/guard), my argument validation library. See [string guards](https://github.com/safakgur/guard/blob/dev/src/Guard.String.cs) for example. The reason why null values are allowed are [here](https://github.com/safakgur/guard/blob/dev/docs/design-decisions.md#optional-preconditions).

Comment: The whole nullable reference types concept is a compromise where the leading issues are not wanting to have to introduce (or expand) something like `Nullable<T>` for reference types, not breaking existing code, and still get some value out of it. The attribute method is actually quite good, but it means two method signatures that only differ in reference nullability are unfortunately considered equal, and thus not allowed.

Comment: I wouldn't prefer an overload anyway, I'd very much like to have additional attributes for annotating generic type nullability relations.

Comment: You should post a feature request for the Roslyn team then I guess.

Comment: You can use `Bar(foo1!)` to get rid of the warning. If you test the code in Sharplab.io you'll see that even the generated C# code is identical in both cases. The same type, `Foo<string>` is generated. The code doesn't change if you use `!` or not, only the warnings.

Comment: @Panagiotis - I know, but this is not a realistic approach when designing an API since you can't just ask the users to ignore the warnings. I'd use anything I can in `Foo<T>`'s or `Bar`'s definitions but I can't modify the call site.

Comment: @Lasse - "Currently this can't be done", preferably with some links to the official channels where I can raise my concern, would be a perfectly valid answer if this is indeed the case. So feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it in a few days providing no one shows up with a working solution.

Comment: @ŞafakGür in that case create overloads. You're asking to validate nullability 3 levels *away* from `Bar` - you want to validate nullability of the `Value` property of a generic type used by Bar.  `Bar` itself doesn't say anything about the nullability of either the parameters or results, so you can't use any of the pre- or post-condition attributes. If the method threw on null for example, you could specify that the result is non-nullable even if the compiler can't discern this

Comment: @Panagiotis - Yeah, but if null wasn't a valid value, I`d just accept a `Foo<string>` instead of `Foo<string?>`. Creating an overload would be a good enough compromise if reference type nullability had an effect on the method signature but that's not the case either, so I have to use different method names for our pseudo-overloads. Can you recommend a naming pattern for this?

Comment: @thehennyy's comment gave me an [idea](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwGIA7AV11wENhcYACGY62gWACh2ABAZjtkoAmEYrgCedAM4YopMBjoAxCBAA8AFQB87AN7s6+uj0XKAFGroA3SrgCUeg7rYHndAGrXS9ALyXrAbnt9AF9Aw15zd1xPOm06AHMYDD86ELZUrgAmOgAhSgAvHXZU50zDAEYAdkKnAyNOMqRjVU0cyih1DRMlZo06ADNlOxqXOgB3AAsYWDpzEFa8gH5QxxH9bD66EwGIADpI6OwJOjIKGxi6AHoAKjoAZQgAW0Tx7GI4uiuLlNDnGFwJeixa53R70CAYSZQOgQ17vT7fYYuTgVfrKAKI9KIzgZDLLH4GKxQ7ZlOg+YgwUZNFS5PKdcmUmkmGw2dGrXxQ2AYEk+XJQLbKMos9j4/SE1EQLJkilUmkLOnkWys1ZizmS1p87YZIUYgzCtLsIA=) - I can make `Bar` generic and add the desired type as a type constraint.

Comment: Unfortunately though, sealed classes like string can't be used as type constraints.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36894

Answer (score 1):

For a `Foo<string?> Bar(Foo<string?> foo)` method, the type parameter of the accepted foo has no relation to the type parameter of the returned foo. And currently, there is no way to annotate the intended relationship of their nullabilities.

Type parameter `T` in a generic `Foo<T> Bar<T>(Foo<T> foo)` method, however, would allow us to share the nullability and we could add a generic type constraint like `where T : MyType?` in order to use type-specific functionality.

Unfortunately, we can't write `where T : string?`, because C# does not allow sealed classes to be used as type constraints. This is reasonable as it wouldn`t make sense before - why would we design the method as generic at the first place if there is only one type we can use anyway? Well, with C# 8 and nullable reference types are out in the wild, I think we may have a valid reason now. Maybe the team can lift this restriction as they lifted it for enums.

To answer my own question:

- There is no attribute to annotate this use case.
- Generics can be used with type constraints but only with types that are not sealed.

As a side note: Even though C# doesn't let us use sealed types as type constraints, IL does. So if weaving is an option, we can actually add sealed type constraints to generic type parameters. A solution like [ExtraConstraints](https://github.com/Fody/ExtraConstraints) can be extended to provide this functionality.